# R DataFrame indexing issue. 2 becomes NA

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

OBJECTIVE:
I am trying to add values to a dataframe, using a for loop with a counter as the index (by row) for the dataframe.

PROBLEM:
When the counter == 2, the row index is written as NA. Then, 3 and so on are added as expected. 1 also works fine.

ODDITIES:
This is not local, and is reproducible in online R sandboxes.

I can use "[2,]" to access the dataframe index, even though this row is labeled "NA".

When the counter == 2, I can add this value (2) into rows.

EXAMPLE:

```
samplez <- c("a","b","c","d")
print(samplez)

sampleStatsDF <- data.frame(
        foo              = 0,
        bar              = 0,
        stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

print(sampleStatsDF)

sampleNum <- 0

# For each sample in group...
for (sampleId in samplez) {

    sampleNum <- sampleNum + 1

    # Default stat values
    sampleStatsDF[sampleNum,]$foo <- sampleNum
    sampleStatsDF[sampleNum,]$bar <- sampleNum

    print(sampleStatsDF[sampleNum,])

}

print(sampleStatsDF)

print(sampleStatsDF[2,])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
  foo bar
1   0   0
  foo bar
1   1   1
   foo bar
NA   2   2
  foo bar
3   3   3
  foo bar
4   4   4
   foo bar
1    1   1
NA   2   2
3    3   3
4    4   4
   foo bar
NA   2   2
```

So... why doesn't R like the number 2 as a dataframe row index ???

Comment: Why this happens can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51387451/row-numbers-differ-na-vs-1-when-adding-first-row-to-empty-data-frame

Comment: This problem goes away if you do `sampleStatsDF[sampleNum,"foo"] <- sampleNum` rather than `sampleStatsDF[sampleNum,]$foo <- sampleNum`

Comment: @MrFlick I think that's as close to a duplicate as we're going to get. That answer literally walks through how the first NA is created via subsetting a row that doesn't exist and then how the subsequent NAs get replaced by the row number to avoid duplicated row names.

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick for the clear explanation and simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace:

```
sampleStatsDF[sampleNum,]$foo <- sampleNum
sampleStatsDF[sampleNum,]$bar <- sampleNum
```

with:

```
sampleStatsDF <- rbind(sampleStatsDF, c(sampleNum, sampleNum))
```

it will produce what seems to be your intended outcome:

```
print(sampleStatsDF)
  foo bar
1   0   0
2   1   1
3   2   2
4   3   3
5   4   4
```

I'm not quite sure what the explanation behind the problem you're seeing is. My guess is it might have something to do with setting a value for a row that doesn't exist yet (specifically in a one-row dataframe).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're appending new rows to `sampleStatsDF` and row 2 is the first appended row (why it defaults to `NA`, I don't know). But if you initialize the data.frame with

```
sampleStatsDF <- data.frame(
    foo              = c(0,0),
    bar              = c(0,0),
    stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

you'll see that row 3 gets the `NA`. Maybe you want to initialize `sampleStatsDF` to the known number of rows you'll have. Alternatively, you can set the rownames after with

```
rownames(sampleStatsDF) = 1:NROW(sampleStatsDF)
```